# Using geojson and javascript to create map markers and heatmap, is not working

Tags: javascript, html, geojson

Can anyone help in resolving this issue?, I am trying to create a map showing map markers of power plants in the US and also a heatmap later on. The problem with my code is that my map is not even showing when it goes live. I have attached the config, location and index files to help with finding the issue. I initially had a local csv file, which I converted to geojson which was then deployed on github.

config.js

```
// API key
const API_KEY = "pk.eyJ1IjoidGF1cmVhbmgiLCJhIjoiY2tmb21yc2tzMDFnYTJ0bXVuMzVub2tvYyJ9.vhUstehmvTj6HgfalepX8w";
```

location.js

```
var myMap = L.map("map", {
  center: [37.7749, -122.4194],
  zoom: 13
});

// Adding tile layer
L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}", {
  attribution: "© <a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/'>Mapbox</a> © <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a></strong>",
  tileSize: 512,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  id: "mapbox/streets-v11",
  accessToken: API_KEY
}).addTo(myMap);

var url = "https://taureanh.github.io/geojson/";

d3.json(url, function(response) {

  console.log(response);

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var geometry = response[i].geometry;

    if (geometry) {
      L.marker([geomtery.coordinates[1], geometry.coordinates[0]]).addTo(myMap);
    }
  }

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Map Markers</title>

    <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <!-- Our CSS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- API key -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/config.js"></script>


    <!-- Leaflet JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <!-- D3 CDN -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/location.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/heatmap.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Leaflet heatmap plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/leaflet-heat.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`d3.json` expects JSON, but your endpoint is returning HTML:

```
curl -I https://taureanh.github.io/geojson/
HTTP/2 200
server: GitHub.com
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

You should update your endpoint so that is actually returns JSON: `content-type: application/json`; just data, no `<html>` tags.

Alternatively, you could update location.js to get the endpoint (`d3.request(url, function(html)`), then parse the response into JSON yourself (strip the html tags, then use `JSON.parse`). This will work, but it's messy and not ideal.